# Throwing an exception instead of error from a PHP extension

Tags: php, c, documentation

Another co-worker and I have been heavily modifying the PHP Zookeeper extension but the one thing really bothering me is the reliance on PHP error's vs Exceptions.

The original source is here: http://github.com/andreiz/php-zookeeper/blob/master/php_zookeeper.c#L209

Instead it would be nicer to throw up a Zookeeper_NodeNotExists or similar except I have no idea what the API call in c is.

I've tried googling and got a cornucopia result set of Exceptions in the PHP language, the PHP manual doesn't seem to mention them, and I can't remember which PHP stock extensions throw exception for you.  Is there an alternative source of documentation on the PHP/Zend c API out there?

Comment: Last time I looked (it was a long time ago) PHP was written in `C`. There are no exceptions in `C`.

Comment: Look through the source of various exceptions that do throw exceptions (can't think of any offhand... brain fried), and see what they use.

Comment: @pmg No the C language doesn't have a concept for try/catch... but PHP5 does, so there has to be a zend_ or php_ API function that throws an exception from the extension into a PHP script

Comment: @Marc B Heh, I can't remember any either ( though I remember some of them do throw exceptions )

Comment: Man... literally brain fried. long day. "the source of various extensions" is what I should have said.... and now I'm off to bed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked at the source code for PHP 5.3's Sqlite extension, specifically Sqlite.c which I knew threw an exception and found

via sqlite - https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3/ext/sqlite/sqlite.c#L46

```
#include "zend_exceptions.h"
```

In zend_exceptions.h, it looks like a RuntimeException can be raised via a simple call to

```
zend_throw_exception(NULL, "Some text")
```

as explained here https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3/Zend/zend_exceptions.h#L43

The Sqlite3 extension uses it like so:

```
zend_throw_exception(zend_exception_get_default(TSRMLS_C), "Already initialised DB Object", 0 TSRMLS_CC);
```

where I infer that zend_exception_get_default() gets a reference/handle to RuntimeException, the 2nd argument is the Exception message, and all other work is delegated.

Answer (score 0):

pdo is an example

http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo/pdo.c?revision=296679&view=markup

http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c?revision=302783&view=markup

(search for "exception").